# jQuery Mobile: Making a search-button that expands into a search input

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

The code below will place a search button in the top left corner of the header, you can check how it looks here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9yw8r1zh/

What I'm looking to do is to make this button expand into a search field when you tap it, something like this, except the other way:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ExpandingSearchBar/

Do jQuery Mobile have something like this already built in, or do you have to make the whole thing yourself?

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
      <a href="#expand" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="search" data-corners="false" data-role="button"
           class="ui-btn-left ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inline ui-shadow"></a>
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/9yw8r1zh/1/

Comment: Nice man, thanks for pointing me in the right direction